# Centimeters to Pixels Conversion

Tags: java

how to convert 
1 cm to ?px

this conversion used in html parser

`%` conversion is -> `(allToPx[0]) * 16)/100) px`

`pt` conversion is -> `(allToPx[0]) * 16)/12) px`

`em` conversion is -> `(allToPx[0]) * 16)/1) px`

but how to convert in `cm` ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to figure out the pixel density for the display you work on. This might be drastically different. You have to get these data:

- width of screen
- height of screen
- vertical pixels
- horizontal pixels

Then you can calculate what the actual size of a given pixel vertically and horizontally...

But obtaining this kind of information is not always possible. You might have to use some platform dependant trickery to get these, if even possible... Also, you didn't specify what kind of UI library you use. That might be of help for us to be able give advice.

Comment: *"obtaining this kind of information is not always possible."*  Especially not if the screen is being projected onto any old flat surface.  ;)

Comment: Whoa, I forgot about projectors. I'll remember this from now on. Also, I wonder what's with video glasses regarding the same question... I didn't think out of the box enough this time...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `cm` conversion as the size of the elements in `cm` depends heavily on the screen density (pixels per inch or cm), which you can't access on most devices

Answer (score 1):

It would not be impossible to convert `cm` to `px` since they are **not** of the same unit types.

`cm` is an *absolute* length unit while `px` is a *relative* length unit

Its just like saying, "Can I convert kilos to hours?"

Use this as reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537660(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think a better analogy would be pounds & kilos, in that the first is a force (mass x gravitational pull), while the second is a mass.  An astronaut of 80 kilos will have a weight of 0 pounds, when in orbit (free fall).

Comment: That might have been different from what I was thinking. :)